# What is correlationId and sequenceNumber and what role it plays to aggregation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm using scatter gather pattern which uses three parallel flows. I can see the aggregated groupMessage consists of the responses coming in order of which comes first. Can I change the index of the messages that are grouped together in aggregate() method by using correlationId and sequenceNumber?

```
 public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                        .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                gatherer -> gatherer.releaseLockBeforeSend(true))
            .log("Gatherer")
            .aggregate(aggregatingAndFormingRequestForFlow4())
            .to(flow4())

public MessageGroupProcessor aggregatingAndFormingRequestForFlow4() {
    return group -> {
         System.out.println("Get Messages: " + group.getMessages())
  // here I need to send three responses as arguments to do further processing but as group is a list in the runtime I don't know the index       
         prepareRequest()
/// }
```

Here if I see the log :

```
INFO [pool-12-thread-1]Gatherer:GenericMessage [payload=[response from flow1, response from flow2, response from flow3 ], headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[f4da9a6f-f27d-91ac-cbef-5106eb614d62, 1, 1]], errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1b6efbf0, sequenceSize=1, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1b6efbf0,correlationId=f4da9a6f-f27d-91ac-cbef-5106eb614d62, id=378f5406-ce9e-19fb-c909-5d5c7c4093c0, timestamp=1662660858032}]

Get Messages: [payload=[response from flow1, response from flow2, response from flow3 ], headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[f4da9a6f-f27d-91ac-cbef-5106eb614d62, 1, 1]], errorChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1b6efbf0, sequenceSize=1, replyChannel=org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@1b6efbf0,correlationId=f4da9a6f-f27d-91ac-cbef-5106eb614d62, id=378f5406-ce9e-19fb-c909-5d5c7c4093c0, timestamp=1662660858032}]
```

u can see the log it's an array of three responses combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See theory about an Aggregator pattern in the EIP book: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Aggregator.html.

Then take a look into its implementation in Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#aggregator.

Indeed a correlation details is important info to determine that some messages belong to the same group to emit a single aggregated message for them.

Exactly this approach is done in the Scatter Gather as well: when we distribute message for recipient, we populate the mentioned headers into its copies for every recipient. The aggregator will gather replies and correlate them to group according to their correlation details headers.

There is no guarantee in which order replies come to the aggregator, but you can add an `outputProcessor(MessageGroupProcessor outputProcessor)` option to sort messages in the group whatever way you need. This callback happens before the output message is emitted.

**UPDATE**

Thank you for sharing the code! Now it makes it more cleaner.

So, you have two levels of correlation: splitter-aggregator in the begging and in the end of flow. And then scatter-gather in the middle. This is correct that you see a single message with a list of payloads in the final aggregator: just because you use a default strategy for that `gatherer`. What I suggested to do is to use a custom group processor exactly on the `gatherer`. All the logic I explained you in comment is exactly for that level, but you misled me to an aggregator I didn't know until now. When you look into that custom processor on the gatherer, you'll see 3 messages in a group and there you can sort them respectively by their `sequenceNumber`.

Comment: In outputProcessor I'll get the MessageGroup, as the exact index is not known so it's becoming costly operation to distinguish different output. Can I order the messages based on the sequenceNumber that is present in the header of each flow? So that I'll know the index of the responses.

Comment: I'm not sure what is "costly" over there. The `MessageGroup` is a container for already correlated and ready for output messages. So, yes, you can use that `sequenceNumber` header to sort messages from the `MessageGroup.getMessages()` and build respective single message for the output.

Comment: what I meant is - MessageGroup is a container where all my three parallel flows responses(payload) should reside. But how do I get the index for a specific response message ? I need to do something like this -  List<Message<?>> messages = group.streamMessages().collect(Collectors.toList());
ArrayList<Object> payloads = (ArrayList<Object>) messages.get(0).getPayload(); Now from this payload as the indexing happened randomly so I don't know in which index which response is there. So I need to go to each index and compare and then can decide. I hope it make sense to you

Comment: No, this one does not make sense to me. Why do you do `(ArrayList<Object>) messages.get(0).getPayload();`? Is your single response really a list? How about others? This probably need to be explained properly in your question: what exactly your distributed services are doing and what they are returning? My point is that we send a single message to the service with respective correlation headers and we expect a single reply. We correlate then those messages with same headers. What you have in payloads is out of an aggregator scope.

Comment: here I have 3 parallel flows. Now after all parallel flow runs the responses getting stored in group messages which is having different groups of messages. Now in each group I'll have payload and header. Here as correlationIds are same for all three parallel flows so I have only 1 group. Now let's say I get three responses from three flows i.e., "A","B","C" and these responses will be stored into that group's payload as an arraylist. So as the responses are being stored randomly so I don't know in the runtime which responses sits in which index of that group's payload's arraylist.

Comment: Each flow will be assigned with a correlationId and sequenceNumber but once it's aggregated then these specific headers for specific flow is not present. Here in my case the group's header will have sequenceSize & sequenceNumber equals to 1. Here the responses are getting set to the group's paylod's arraylist randomly and I want it to set as per the sequence number so that in the runtime the indices of the responses don't change.

Comment: And to clarify my single response is not list it's String. But three responses are saved in a arraylist. And the indices are not known to me beforehand because in runtime its getting set randomly which gives response first.

Comment: There is not payload in a group. The group contains correlated messages. And those messages have the payload from individual reply. We probably need to see your configuration. Please, edit your question with respective code.

Comment: See also docs for Scatter-Gather to determine what you may miss in your configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-routing.html#scatter-gather. For example: `If you want to rely on only the default correlationStrategy for the recipient-list-router and the aggregator, you should specify apply-sequence="true".`

Comment: I have updated the post. Kindly see to it.

Comment: Thank you! See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Now it make sense Artem. Thanks a ton.